# Currency Converter Not Working with Javascript & HTML

Tags: javascript, html, converters

I am making a currency converter for cryptos, but I'm getting a problem with it working. Here is the source code. Now I tried several methods to make it work, but I either did not succeed or only partially.

HTML:

```
         <html>
           <head>
           </head>
           <body>

            <input oninput="convert()" onchange="convert()"  type="value" name="input" id="currencycoininsert" placeholder="0.00"/>
        <!--    <button type="button" id="btncur-insert"> -->
                <select name="dropdowncurrency" id="selectcurinsert">
                    <option value="BTC" id="selectcurinsert1" >BITCOIN (BTC)</option>
                    <option value="ETH" id="selectcurinsert2"  selected>ETHERIUM (ETH)</option>
                    <option value="LTC" id="selectcurinsert3" >LITECOIN (LTC)</option>
                    <option value="ZEC" id="selectcurinsert4" >ZCASH (ZEC)</option>
                    <option value="XMR" id="selectcurinsert5" >MONERO (XMR)</option>
                </select>
        <!--    </button> -->
            <button type="submit" name="smbtcur" id="sbmtcurinsert" onclick="convert()">
            Convert
            </button>
            <input type="value" id="received"/>

         </body>
         </html>
```

Any Help is appreciated.
And here is the Javascript Part:
JS:

```
                var rates = [10500, 920, 220, 310, 460];

                var BTCUSD = rates[0];
                var ETHUSD = rates[1];
                var LTCUSD = rates[2];
                var XMRUSD = rates[3];
                var ZECUSD = rates[4];

            function convert(){


                var x1 = document.getElementById("selectcurinsert1").value;
                var x2 = document.getElementById("selectcurinsert2").value;
                var x3 = document.getElementById("selectcurinsert3").value;
                var x4 = document.getElementById("selectcurinsert4").value;
                var x5 = document.getElementById("selectcurinsert5").value;
                if (document.getElementById("selectcurinsert").value = x1)
                {
                  function convertbtc()
                {   
                        z = BTCUSD;
                        x = document.getElementById("currencycoininsert").value;
                        document.getElementById("receivedmufg").value = x * z;   
                }
                }
                else if (document.getElementById("selectcurinsert").value = x2)
                {
                function converteth()
                {

                        z = BTCUSD;
                        x = document.getElementById("currencycoininsert").value;
                        document.getElementById("receivedmufg").value = x * z; 

                }
                }
                else if (document.getElementById("selectcurinsert").value = x3)
                {
                function converteth()
                {

                        z = BTCUSD;
                        x = document.getElementById("currencycoininsert").value;
                        document.getElementById("receivedmufg").value = x * z; 

                }
                }
                else if (document.getElementById("selectcurinsert").value = x4)
                {
                function converteth()
                {

                        z = BTCUSD;
                        x = document.getElementById("currencycoininsert").value;
                        document.getElementById("receivedmufg").value = x * z; 

                }
                }
                else if (document.getElementById("selectcurinsert").value = x5)
                {
                function converteth()
                {

                        z = BTCUSD;
                        x = document.getElementById("currencycoininsert").value;
                        document.getElementById("receivedmufg").value = x * z; 

                }
                }
                }


            </script>
```

Any help is appreciated, hopefully this will turn up well.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working? Specific functions?  Are you receiving errors?

Comment: No, not receiving any errors. When I select the option of BITCOIN, Etherium etc., and place a value, the result is not calculated

Comment: dont use function inside if statement directly use the statements

Comment: actually you are only declaring function inside there it is not being called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `convert` function's definition you define other functions inside conditionals, but you're never actually calling those functions.

you can define `converteth`, etc. elsewhere and just call it like `converteth()` inside of the conditional.

Pseudocode:

```
function converteth () {
    ... converteth code ...
}

function convertbtc () {
    ... convertbtc code ...
}

function convert () {
    ... get element by id statements
    if (document.getElementById("selectcurinsert").value = x1) {
        convertbtc();
    } ... other conditional statements ...
}
```

Also in your conditional statements you've used the assignment operator `=` instead of a logical operator to compare the two values.  I assume you want to use `===` or `==`.

Comment: When I do that, only one of the options is running, and specifically the one with --if-- statement, the rest with --else if-- are not showing values (only the same one of --if-- statement, which here is the BTC or bitcoin).

Comment: Tried to eliminate all elseif(s) but then, only the last if statement prevails, the rest don't work too.

Comment: @GreakFreak  The goal is not to remove the else if statements.  The goal is to change the work that is being done inside of each.  Inside of each you are _defining_ functions not _calling_ functions.

Comment: Agree. After I defined the functions outside the convert() function, and called them in it, I still have the problem. Only one option is calculated while the rest are not, try it for yourself, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: You're conditional statements don't have equality operators `==`, and rather have assignment operators `=`.  Adding to the answer.

Comment: Following a style guide for your code might help you catch these errors more quickly.  I really like to use StandardJS.  My code editor (Atom) has a linter for this style and it shows me these errors automatically.

Comment: Now, that works. Would probably use StandardJS for the future. Thank you!

Comment: @GreakFreak Would you mind marking this answer as correct.